# Vaex - NameError: Column or variable 'example_string' does not exist

Tags: python, vaex

I've recently started to use vaex for its great potentialities on large set of data.
I'm trying to apply the following function:

```py
def get_columns(v: str, table_columns: List, pref: str = '', suff: str = '') -> List:
        return [table_columns.index(i) for i in table_columns if (pref + v + suff) in i][0]
```

to a df as follows:

```py
df["column_day"] = df.apply(get_columns, arguments=[df.part_day, table.columns.tolist(), "total_4wk_"])
```

but I get the error when I run `df["column_day"]`:

```py
NameError: Column or variable 'total_4wk_' does not exist.
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong, since other functions (with only one argument) I used with apply worked fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe vaex expects the arguments passed to `apply` to actually be expressions.

In your case `table.columns.tolist()` and `"total_4wk_"` are not expressions so it complains. So I would re-write your `get_columns` function such that it only takes in expressions as arguments, and I believe that will work.